# Is it natural to say "Sorry for disturbing (you)" after you have "disturbed" someone?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

"I think I'm going to head off. Sorry for disturbing."

- Is it natural to say "Sorry for disturbing" after you have "disturbed" someone?
- Should I add "you" after "disturbing" or is it not necessary?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the differences between "sorry to keep you waiting" and "sorry for keeping you waiting."?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/167669/what-are-the-differences-between-sorry-to-keep-you-waiting-and-sorry-for-keep)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to say what was disturbed: "you", "your room", "the fish tank", "the experiment". Sorry for disturbing your Aunt Jane.

"Interrupting" is different:
Sorry for interrupting.
Sorry for interrupting you.
Sorry for interrupting the meeting.
These are all OK.