# "sorry to interrupt" vs. "sorry for interrupting"

Tags: prepositions

Ronald is talking with Anthony. All of a sudden, Kenneth runs over here and says

> "sorry to interrupt, the boss just gave a job to Anthony which is quite urgent"

or

> "sorry for interrupting, ..."

which one should Kenneth say?

[Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sorry%20to%20interrupt%2C%20sorry%20for%20interrupting&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Csorry%20to%20interrupt%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bsorry%20to%20interrupt%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BSorry%20to%20interrupt%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Csorry%20for%20interrupting%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bsorry%20for%20interrupting%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BSorry%20for%20interrupting%3B%2Cc0) shows both are common.

[image]

[What are the differences between "sorry to keep you waiting" and "sorry for keeping you waiting."?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/167669/115654) gives a nuanced difference in context. How about the example of Kenneth?

Comment: Is the first quote an actual quotation from somewhere? Did they use "emergent" or was it "urgent"?

Comment: @AIQ You're right, it should be "urgent". Thank you.

Comment: These should help a bit: ['I have decided to purchase a jet for getting to NYC and back more quickly.'](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/59468/i-have-decided-to-purchase-a-jet-for-getting-to-nyc-and-back-more-quickly), [How can I decide when to use “for” + “-ing” or “to” + infinitive in a sentence?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/24553/how-can-i-decide-when-to-use-for-ing-or-to-infinitive-in-a-sentence), [To + infinitive and for + verb-ing to express purpose](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv284.shtml)